# Netty: SslProvider.OPENSSL_REFCNT example

Tags: openssl, netty, tcnative

I am using `netty-tcnative` with `SslProvider.OPENSSL` provider. I see a warning msg in GC log analyzer about `finalizers` which I am suspecting is mostly because of it.

```
[Warning] At one point 25872 objects were queued for finalization. 
Using finalizers is not recommended as it can slow garbage collection and cause wasted space in the heap. 
Consider reviewing your application for occurrences of the finalize() method.
```

I see Netty provides another option `SslProvider.OPENSSL_REFCNT` which does not have finalizers and instead implements ReferenceCounted.

- I am wondering if it is a drop-in replacement of
  `SslProvider.OPENSSL` or if it needs more changes.
- **Is it production ready? I see it is marked as `@UnstableApi`. Any
  known side effects or issues?**
- Does it perform better than `SslProvider.OPENSSL` for low latency
  high throughput system?

```
SslProvider provider = SslProvider.isAlpnSupported(SslProvider.OPENSSL) ? SslProvider.OPENSSL : SslProvider.JDK;
logger.info("SSL provider: {}", provider);
sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(keyManagerFactory)
    .sslProvider(provider)
    .ciphers(cypherList)
    .applicationProtocolConfig(new ApplicationProtocolConfig(
        Protocol.ALPN,
        SelectorFailureBehavior.NO_ADVERTISE,
        SelectedListenerFailureBehavior.ACCEPT,
        ApplicationProtocolNames.HTTP_1_1
    ))
    .sessionCacheSize(SSL_SESSION_CACHE_SIZE) // 1800 -> 30 mins
    .sessionTimeout(SSL_SESSION_CACHE_TIMEOUT_SECOND) // 1024 * 100 -> 1000_00 sessions
    .build();


// DefaultServerInitializer
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
...
if (sslContext != null) {
  pipeline.addLast(sslContext.newHandler(ch.alloc()));
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take attention, that the Netty API Reference on [public final class SslContextBuilder](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/ssl/SslContextBuilder.html) says:

> If sslProvider(SslProvider) is set to SslProvider.OPENSSL_REFCNT then the caller is responsible for releasing this object, or else native memory may leak.

That corresponds to the description of [public interface ReferenceCounted](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/util/ReferenceCounted.html), beginning with the sentence:

> A reference-counted object that requires explicit deallocation.

So its not a drop-in, as you have to replace the finalizer which would otherwise take care of deallocation. See e.g. this [Github issue](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/10397) for an example considering possible practical consequences.